# How to order rows according to select statement

Tags: mysql

So I have query:

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.staff_id, t1.longname, t2.*, t3.longname as appraisor_name, t4.dep, t2.staff_id as check_id, t5.deptname FROM users t1
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT * FROM quartz_quarter2 WHERE staff_id = '1001128' AND date = '2017'
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM quartz_quarter3 WHERE staff_id = '1001128' AND date = '2017'
        UNION             
        SELECT * FROM quartz_quarter4 WHERE staff_id = '1001128' AND date = '2017'
        UNION             
        SELECT * FROM quartz_quarter1 WHERE staff_id = '1001128' AND date = '2018'            
    )t2 ON t1.staff_id = t2.staff_id
    LEFT JOIN( SELECT * FROM users )t3 ON t2.appraisor_id = t3.staff_id
    LEFT JOIN( SELECT * FROM quartz_department )t4 ON t2.role = t4.role
    LEFT JOIN( SELECT * FROM ref_department )t5 ON t1.fkdeptid = t5.deptid
    WHERE t1.staff_id = '1001128'
```

I want to get data exactly in the same order like I select so it should be:

```
| username | staff_id | quarter |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| YEVGENIY |  1001128 |    2    |
| YEVGENIY |  1001128 |    3    |
| YEVGENIY |  1001128 |    4    |
| YEVGENIY |  1001128 |    1    |
```

But what i get is:

[image]

Is there any way to order it according to select statements?

Comment: You could try `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(quarter, '2,3,4,1')`. It's unclear what the `quarter` field name is from your question, so update as necessary.

Comment: @fubar `quarter` is just column name from the table. It worked. You can add it as answer I will mark it as correct one. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(quarter, '2,3,4,1);
```

This function will return the position of the value in the set specified.